# Переделать char функцию под int

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Здравствуйте, нужно переделать данную функцию, так, что б вместо подпоследовательности char, она проверяла подпоследовательность int:

```
int check_subsequence (char a[], char b[]) {
   int c, d;

   c = d = 0;

   while (a[c] != '\0') {
      while ((a[c] != b[d]) && b[d] != '\0') {
         d++;
      }
      if (b[d] == '\0')
         break;
      d++;
      c++;
   }
   if (a[c] == '\0')
      return 1;
   else
      return 0;
}
```

Входны данные в функцию:

```
bool check_subsequence(int *A, int *B, int n, int m)//n- длина A, m - длина B
```

Comment: Так у вас и тип выходных данных поменялся...

Comment: @Byulent сути не меняет, 1 - true, 0 - false

Comment: Вот работа вашей **исходной** функции - http://ideone.com/zgQV63 Вы уверены, что она проверяет наличие подпоследовательности? :)

Answer (score 1):

Простой дословный перевод вашей функции -

```
bool check_subsequence(int *a, int *b, int n, int m)
{
   int c = 0, d = 0;
   while (c != n) {
      while((d != m) && (a[c] != b[d])) {
         d++;
      }
      if (d == m)
         break;
      d++;
      c++;
   }
   if (c == n)
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
```

Не компилировал и не тестировал, но слишком просто, чтоб сильно ошибиться :)

Comment: Неа, не правильно работает.

Comment: В этом случае приводите пример входных данных (даже как вызываете) и ожидаемый результат.

Comment: Проверьте, работает ли исходная функция для строк :)

Comment: Ок, ну вот я ввожу: {6. 7. 8. 9. 10} - A, {6, 10} - B  - TRUE ||
 {6. 7. 8. 9. 10} - A, {10, 6} - B  - FALSE

Comment: @Harry, в первоисточнике всё работало)

Comment: Берем **вашу** функцию, вводим "67890" - a, "60" - b - , "67890" - a, "06" - b - получаем два false - это верный результат?

Comment: @Harry, функция проверяет является ли вторая последовательность подпоследовательностью первой. Ответ написал выше.

Comment: Тогда ваша исходная функция работает неверно. Если неверен исходный текст, чего ждать от перевода? :)

Answer (score -1):

Написал альтернативный:

```
bool check_subsequence(int *a, int *b, int n, int m)
{
    while ((n > 0) && (m > 0)) {
        if (a[n] == b[m]) {
            --n;
            --m;
        }
        else
        {
            --n;
        }
    }
    if (m == 0)return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: Сформулируйте, **что должна делать ваша функция**. Не код, а именно словами - какой результат она должна давать.